# General Solution for Differential Equation with Inverse Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given that $f:\Re \to \Re$ is invertible, differentiable and monotonic increasing.

Need to find a general solution for the equation:

$f'(y)y' = xf(y)$

I'm working to either separate variables or to put the equation in linear form of $y$ but no success so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:
$$f'(y)y'=xf(y)$$
$$\frac{f'(y)}{f(y)}dy=x\:dx$$
$$\ln|f(y)|=\frac{x^2}{2}+\text{constant}$$
$$f(y)=C\:e^{x^2/2}$$
$$y=f^{-1}\left(C\:e^{x^2/2} \right)$$
Of course, you have to justify the validity of the main steps.

Comment: Since $f(y)$ is onto it must have a root. can we still divide by zero (ignore this root and then the anti-derivative will still be the same since we've had to change the function only at one spot?)